# Multi-sig Safe (formerly Gnosis Safe) ERC-4337 transaction with gas abstraction

Tags: multisignature, safe-core-sdk, erc-4337

Having a hard time estimating gas using **eth_estimateUserOperationGas** for a Safe **execTransaction** call wrapped in a **UserOperation**.

I have a safe contract deployed with the ethInfinitism ERC4337 Safe module deployed and enabled on the safe. I have gone through the motions of creating and encoding the **callData** (with ABI and Safe SDK, both give exact same result), then passing that on to the UserOperation payload.

Regardless of what I try, I get this error: code: -32500, message: AA23 reverted (or OOG).

- 32500 - transaction rejected by entryPoint’s simulateValidation, during wallet creation or validation (so guessing it's getting to the entrypoint but then some validation fails. Signatures? Paymaster? who knows)
- AA23 reverted (or OOG) -

I have substituted paymasterAndData as well as the signature with recommended dummy values.

- Sender is the Safe address
- initCode is 0x since the safe is already deployed
- callData derived from Safe SDK encoding of the execTransaction parameters
- all gas related fields are 0x1 since they should be ignored (I'm trying to derive these values from eth_estimateUserOperationGas call in the first place?)
- paymasterAndData as well as signature values are dummy values as specified in Alchemy docs here https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/eth-estimateuseroperationgas
- entry point address derived from eth_supportedEntryPoints

Perhaps I am missing something fundamental in my understanding?

In short: trying to set up multi-sig Safe to use 4337 for gas abstraction and I'm getting nowhere.

P.S I've used Stackup's SDK + services to achieve something similar but using zeroDev Kernel smart wallet. Using Safe is a hard requirement though. Gelato relay is a decent alternative but I would very much like to get 4337 working with Safe as it's set to be the future for gas abstraction and Safe is a great smart contract wallet implementation.

Comment: If you ever get anywhere with this would love to hear how you did it

Comment: Still no luck - have left this for now in favor of using Gelato with Safe. Will revisit this at some point

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Unfortunately not...